# cvc-complex-type.2.1: Element 'property' must have no character or element information item [children], because the type's content type is empty

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am developing report using jasper report with spring mvc.

[image]

I am getting blank page with following error while clicking on view button.

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 59; columnNumber: 14; cvc-complex-type.2.1: Element 'property' must have no character or element information item [children], because the type's content type is empty.
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:247)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:230)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:218)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:172)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:156)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compile(JasperCompileManager.java:171)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:448)
at com.asd.cms.service.ReportService.getReport(ReportService.java:137)
at com.asd.cms.service.ReportService.generateReport(ReportService.java:58)
at com.asd.cms.controller.KGDLCReport.viewReport(KGDLCReport.java:70)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

...........................................................`

My Code of KGDLCReport.java: 
`com.asd.cms.controller.KGDLCReport.viewReport(KGDLCReport.java:70)`

```
@RequestMapping("/userWiseReportKGDLC")
    public void viewReport(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    String dateFrom = request.getParameter("dateFrom");
    String dateTo = request.getParameter("dateTo");
    String outputFormat = request.getParameter("outputFormat");

    Map<String,Object> param = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    param.put("dateFrom", dateFrom);
    param.put("dateTo", dateTo);

    String path = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/resources/jasper/KGDCL_Report1.jrxml");
**KGDLCReport.java:70** ->  reportService.generateReport(path, outputFormat, param, response);
}
```

`com.asd.cms.service.ReportService.generateReport(ReportService.java:58)`

```
 public void generateReport(String path, String outputFormat, Map<String, Object> param, HttpServletResponse res){
    try{
        if(new File(path).exists()){

            JasperPrint jp = getReport(path, param);  // Line: 58
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            //String outputFormat = req.getParameter("outputFormat");
            if(outputFormat.equals("pdf")){

                JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jp, baos);
                    .............
         }
    }
```

`com.asd.cms.service.ReportService.getReport(ReportService.java:137)`

```
public JasperPrint getReport(String path, Map<String, Object> parameters) throws SQLException{
    JasperPrint print = new JasperPrint();      
    JasperReport report;
    try {

        System.out.println("Path inside ReportService.java line 135"+path); 

        report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(path); //Line: 137 

        print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parameters, jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection());

    } catch (JRException e) {  

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return print;
}
```

Which one may be the cause of getting error? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found the problem after doing some R&D. Problem is in report page. Java code is ok. `JRXmlLoader can't load xml of the report page accurately. So SAXParser wasn't able to parse xml.` That's why I am getting error.